# f:validateRequired does not work on Tomcat

Tags: java, jsf, tomcat

I was using GlassFish on my first JSF project (still learning JSF) and everything was fine. But later, I switched to Tomcat (GlassFish was causing some problems and Tomcat hosting is more cheaply provided). And now I have a problem I just can't solve: validation of forms using f:validate stopped working.

I have already tried many solutions, the most mentioned solution is adding *validation-api.jar* and *hibernate-validator.jar* to libs - that just caused that the form stoped working at all (see error above).

Now I really don't know what to do. I am using NetBeans 7.1, Tomcat 7.0.22.0. Any help is appreciated. Thanks!

Oh yes...and interesting thing is that validating by regular expression (e-mail) works, but only if the input is not empty). (And without the libs added)

Error message after adding *validation-api.jar* and *hibernate-validator.jar* to libs and submiting the form:

```
javax.validation.ValidationException: Unable to find a default provider
    at javax.validation.Validation$GenericBootstrapImpl.configure(Validation.java:264)
    at javax.validation.Validation.buildDefaultValidatorFactory(Validation.java:111)
    at javax.faces.validator.BeanValidator.validate(BeanValidator.java:276)
    at javax.faces.component.UIInput.validateValue(UIInput.java:1149)
    at javax.faces.component.UIInput.validate(UIInput.java:967)
    at javax.faces.component.UIInput.executeValidate(UIInput.java:1233)
    at javax.faces.component.UIInput.processValidators(UIInput.java:698)
    at javax.faces.component.UIForm.processValidators(UIForm.java:253)
    at javax.faces.component.UIComponentBase.processValidators(UIComponentBase.java:1214)
    at javax.faces.component.UIComponentBase.processValidators(UIComponentBase.java:1214)
    at javax.faces.component.UIViewRoot.processValidators(UIViewRoot.java:1172)
    at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.ProcessValidationsPhase.execute(ProcessValidationsPhase.java:76)
    at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.Phase.doPhase(Phase.java:101)
    at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.LifecycleImpl.execute(LifecycleImpl.java:118)
    at javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet.service(FacesServlet.java:409)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:304)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210)
    at org.netbeans.modules.web.monitor.server.MonitorFilter.doFilter(MonitorFilter.java:393)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:243)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:224)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:169)
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:472)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:168)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:100)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve.invoke(AccessLogValve.java:929)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:118)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:405)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:964)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:515)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(JIoEndpoint.java:304)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.runTask(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:886)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:908)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:662)
```

The form:

```html
<h:form>
    <table>
        <tr>
            <th><label for="registration-email">#{usersTexts.email}:</label></th>
            <td>
                <h:inputText value="#{userRegistry.newUser.email}" id="registration-email" validatorMessage="#{msg.invalidEmail}" maxlength="100">
                    <f:validateRequired />
                    <f:validateRegex pattern="^([a-zA-Z0-9_\.\-])+\@(([a-zA-Z0-9\-])+\.)+([a-zA-Z0-9]{2,4})+$" />
                </h:inputText>
            </td>
            <td><p:message for="registration-email" /></td>
            <td rowspan="4">
                <!--p:captcha immediate="true" validatorMessage="#{msg.wrongCaptcha}" requiredMessage="#{formsTexts.captcha} #{msg.isEmpty}" /-->
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <th><label for="registration-name">#{usersTexts.name}:</label></th>
            <td>
                <h:inputText value="#{userRegistry.newUser.name}" id="registration-name" validatorMessage="#{formsTexts.field} #{usersTexts.name} #{msg.isEmpty}" maxlength="100">
                    <f:validateRequired />
                </h:inputText>
            </td>
            <td><p:message for="registration-name" /></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <th><label for="registration-password1">#{usersTexts.password}:</label></th>
            <td>
                <h:inputSecret value="#{userRegistry.newUser.password}" binding="#{password}" id="registration-password1" validatorMessage="#{formsTexts.field} #{usersTexts.password} #{msg.isEmpty}">
                    <f:validateRequired />
                </h:inputSecret>
            </td>
            <td><p:message for="registration-password1" /></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <th><label for="registration-password2">#{usersTexts.passwordAgain}:</label></th>
            <td>
                <h:inputSecret id="registration-password2" validatorMessage="#{msg.passwordsNotEqual}">
                    <f:validateLength minimum="#{user.MIN_PASSWORD_LENGTH}" />
                    <f:validator validatorId="equality" />
                    <f:attribute name="matchAgainst" value="#{password}" />
                </h:inputSecret>
            </td>
            <td><p:message for="registration-password2" /></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td colspan="2" class="submit_row">
                <h:commandButton value="#{usersTexts.register}" action="#{userRegistry.register}" />
            </td>
        </tr>
    </table>
</h:form>
```

Comment: Which JSF impl/version are you using on Tomcat? Which JSF specific configuration parameters do you have in `web.xml`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, with help of a friend I solved it...don't know why, but if input is empty, all f:validate tags are ignored - including `f:validateRequired`, so there was no validaton at all.

Solved that by removing `f:validateRequired` tags and using `required="true"` attribute. So, the input value cant be empty (`required="true"` works) and than, all other f:validators work.

Comment: May be this behavior is related to javax.faces.VALIDATE_EMPTY_FIELDS. Read more here http://andyschwartz.wordpress.com/2009/07/31/whats-new-in-jsf-2/

Answer (score 0):

This is happening because following attribute needs to be set. 
javax.faces.VALIDATE_EMPTY_FIELDS is set to false by default.